# SQLAlchemy self-referential many-to-one relationship: example

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

As I was following the SQLAlchemy documentation on [adjacency list relationships](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/self_referential.html), I was able to replicate their `Node` example as follows:

```
node_tree = Node(data='root', children=[
    Node(data='child1'),
    Node(data='child2', children=[
        Node(data='subchild1'),
        Node(data='subchild2'),
    ]),
    Node(data='child3'),
])
```

However, I was not able to do the same for the many-to-one relationship. What would an example of this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from the example and *many-to-one* class definition provided at the aforementioned link (only difference is the added `remote_side` argument), plus a nice `__repr__` for visualization...

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('node.id'))
    data = Column(String(50))
    parent = relationship("Node", remote_side=[id])

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Node(data={!r})".format(self.data)

# Create tree.
node_tree = Node(data='root')
child1 = Node(data='child1', parent=node_tree)
child2 = Node(data='child2', parent=node_tree)
subchild1 = Node(data='subchild1', parent=child2)
subchild2 = Node(data='subchild2', parent=child2)
child3 = Node(data='child3', parent=node_tree)

# For viewing the session as it works.
def print_session_state(operation):
    print(operation)
    print('new: {}'.format(session.new))
    print('dirty: {}\n'.format(session.dirty))

# When child2 is added...
session.add(child2)
print_session_state('add child2')
# Roll back.
session.rollback()
print_session_state('rollback')
# When subchild1 is added...
session.add(subchild1)
print_session_state('add subchild1')
```

The result:

```
add child2
new: IdentitySet([Node(data='child2'), Node(data='root')])
dirty: IdentitySet([])

rollback
new: IdentitySet([])
dirty: IdentitySet([])

add subchild1
new: IdentitySet([Node(data='subchild1'), Node(data='child2'), Node(data='root')])
dirty: IdentitySet([])
```

The first thing you'll notice is that the instantiation isn't as pretty, since the hierarchy is defined from the bottom up this time.

Also, the cascading behavior is different. With the one-to-many relationship, each `Node` was aware of its *children* (plural) and cascading traveled down the tree.

With many-to-one, each `Node` is only aware of its *parent* (singular) and cascading travels up the tree, such that only those `Node`s in the same branch of the tree as the starting point are reached.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up; you had the example with the parent (many to one) *only*, instead of the bi-directional example. I missed that when first reading through.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I added the class def for clarity in the future. :) I appreciate your `{!r}` tip too - I'm going to use that from now on.